# View all users who have shared calendar with me

Tags: outlook, active-directory, exchange-server

I work in a large e-commerce company. We run largely Windows machines with Exchange. I'd like to get a list of anyone in the company who has their calendar permissions set more openly than the defaults. For example: how do I see who in my company has "full details" of their calendar turned on?

I'm not an admin, just a regular user.
I know how to open and view others' calendars. For example, I know how to open Jane's calendar, or view Bob's calendar, some of whom are sharing more details than others.

Rather than open every person's calendar individually, is there a way to progrmatically view who has more open calendar permissions set to the "everyone" or "all users" group?

Comment: Yes, you could do this programatically, It would effectively involve iterating over a list of all users and trying to access their calendars, however it you had security admin rights then you could also iterate over all users and report the permissions that are set on their calendars. What version of exchange do you have and what code language/runtime would you like to see and example for?

Comment: I'm not sure the version of exchange we have. How would a lay-person go about finding that out?

I'm not sure how to answer your other question (language/runtime). What would make sense in a Windows environment? I suppose another way to phrase that might be: "What would cause little to no red flags raise with my InfoSec or AppSec team?"

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The code language question is about what sort of response you would like to see here, it could be a powershell script, outlook plugin, c# script. What are you going to be comfortable with executing? we want the answer to be as helpful to you as we can. I'd rather not shoot in the dark about that.

Comment: This resource can help you find your current exchange version, following this will also help us identify the type of response that you might find the most useful. http://www.expta.com/2016/06/how-to-quickly-determine-exchange.html

Comment: FYI by not being specific about the expected solution your question runs the risk of being too broad for this forum, check the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section for further guidance around this.